# Prove or Disprove, 3SAT ≤p 2SAT, then P = NP

Tags: satisfiability, discrete-mathematics, p-vs-np

I know that 3SAT is in NP and 2SAT is in P. And 2SAT can reduce to 3SAT just says 3SAT is strictly harder than 2SAT, so I don't think this proves P = NP, but it doesn't seem to disprove it either.

Comment: $A \leq_{P} B$ means that problem $A$ can be reduced to $B$. You seem to have thought that it's the other way around? Also, "2SAT can reduce to 3SAT" only says that 3SAT is "not easier" than 2SAT. It doesn't imply "strictly harder".

Comment: You are right, I just double checked the meaning of the sign.

Answer (score 0):

2SAT can be solved in linear (!) time, so your reduction would certainly prove $P = NP$.

Comment: but 3sat can't be solved in linear time, it's NP. The reduction says 3sat is harder than 2sat, which is like saying NP is harder than P, but how does it prove NP = P ?

Comment: @ChaiTea But your question (or the title at least) is asking about $3SAT\le_p2SAT$. We trivially have $2SAT\le_p3SAT$, it's the other direction which would imply $P=NP$ if true.

Comment: Okay I had the wrong understanding of the 3SAT ≤ 2SAY. So this actually says 3SAT can be reduced to 2SAT, and if true, every instance of 3SAT can be turned into 2SAT and solved in P, and because we know 3SAT is NP, this implied P = NP ?

Comment: @ChaiTea is not because 3SAT is in NP, but because 3SAT is hard for NP (meaning that for any other problem A in NP, $A \leq_p 3SAT$) that we would conclude P = NP if it was true that $3SAT \leq_p 2SAT$.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately it has been shown that 3SAT is not reducible to 2SAT. However, 3SAT is in P where any algorithm solves the general case in P time and space. For such an algorithm see linked paper below.

https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0205064

Comment: You are claiming to have a solution for a well-known, difficult open problem. This is [an extraordinary claim requiring extraordinary evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#.22Extraordinary_claims.22). You have not provided such so there is not much to talk about. Even if you had, this would not be a good post for SE; it is not our goal here to make broad advances to science in a single post. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-to-deal-with-questions-about-crank-heavy-topics) for a related discussion.

Comment: Please don't advertise your paper on multiple posts here... especially ones that aren't particularly related to it.